# Where is the code that this url points to?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have been asked to help out on an MVC5 web site project but it's a bit new to me so I am trying to learn this as I go.  I have been reading through [some tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in) and am making some progress but I am currently a bit stuck.

I am looking at some client side javascript code:

```
onClickMethod = function () {
    $.post('/api/page/item/insert', postData, function (inData) {
    // Do some stuff with the inData ...
    });
};
```

This $.post call is described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp).

The question or confusion I have is that there is no MVC controller called "api" so I don't understand where the url is pointing to.  I can't see a folder in the solution called "api".  Is anyone able to help me find where this post is being sent?

Comment: It's probably an api controller instead of a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be configured as a route in the (RouteConfig) class like following:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

(RouteConfig) is under (App_Start) folder

Comment: Is this also related to the [RouteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: You can find more information in this link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: I've now discovered that some of the controllers have this attribute and the [RoutePrefixAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeprefixattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).  This has lead to much confusion, but thanks for your help.